# In Okinawan, what is the ン in ウチナーンチュ?

Tags: grammar, particles, ryukyuan-languages

The Okinawan word for "Okinawa" is ウチナー, for "person" is チュ, and for "Okinawan" (person) is ウチナーンチュ.

I'd like to know where this ン comes from between the part for "Okinawa" and the part for "person". Japanese 日本人{にほんじん} doesn't seem to have an equivalent.

- Could it be a reduced form of Okinawan ヌ, the equivalant of standard Japanese の?
- Could it be an "epenthetic" sound added in certain kinds of compound words?
- Or something else entirely?

Comment: I would guess it's the same phenomenon which leads to rendaku in Japanese. Note that there are other words like [アチネーンチュ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN00411), [イナカンチュ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN01440), [ヤマトゥンチュ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN41339)...

Comment: @ZhenLin: I suppose it could seem like [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(linguistics)), which is what [rendaku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/rendaku) is an example of. But what makes it different is that in assimilation, properties of one or both sounds influence each other at a point of contact. Whereas [epenthesis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Epenthesis) adds a new sound. Both are for reasons of prosodics though. These examples show that the first component can change but the `n` comes with the `チュ`

Comment: Rendaku is not just a phonological phenomenon. It is thought that the voicing is a remnant of an infix /n/. However I admit I do not know of other words with an infix /n/ in Okinawan – that's mostly because I don't know Okinawan.

Comment: There's an old book called "The Languages of Japan" by Masayoshi Shibatani that might answer your questions, though I can't bet my life. Given the year it's been written, I'm pretty sure it's already free of charge and it could be found somewhere in the depths of the Internet.

Comment: @razorramon I've already checked, and I don't believe *The Languages of Japan* answers this question.  By the way, books published prior to 1923 are in the public domain, but *TLoJ* was published in 1990, rather more recently.  Although it's not free of charge, you can probably find it at a library.

Comment: @snailplane Oh, I was under the impression it was published in year 1900, hence I throwed it in. I have a paper copy, so I'll check what it says about Okinawan.

Comment: Random websites online seem to suggest ンチュ corresponds to Japanese の人, with the ヌ reducing to ン like you suggest, and チュ perhaps coming from と.  Unfortunately, I don't have any good sources to check at the moment, so I'm not really qualified to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Okinawan, what is the ン in ウチナーンチュ?

User ithisa conjectured that this ン is from ぬ, from の.  Let's explore.

> Japanese 日本人【にほんじん】 doesn't seem to have an equivalent [to Okinawan ン].

You're correct, but note that the Japanese *on'yomi* term 日本人【にほんじん】 follows **Chinese** grammar, where "a person from XYZ place" can be expressed as `[PLACE]` + `person`.  For a proper **Japanese** construction, you'd have to compare a *wago* phrase like 大和【やまと】の人【ひと】, where we do indeed find an equivalent with that の.

> Could it be a reduced form of Okinawan ヌ, the equivalent of standard Japanese の?

Yes, it is!

The Shuri-Naha Dialect Dictionary is one very useful online source for readers of Japanese who are interested in "standard" Okinawan.

- http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/index.html

The site has easy lookup starting from either a Japanese word (click on the appropriate starting hiragana) or an Okinawan word (click on the appropriate starting katakana).

For instance, we find that this site has [an entry for ンチュ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN48074), which explains that this means の人, and is a shift or abbreviation from fuller form ヌッチュ.  We can also peruse their entries [for possessive particle ヌ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN40744), equivalent to Japanese の, and [for noun ッチュ](http://ryukyu-lang.lib.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/srnh/details.php?ID=SN25001), equivalent to Japanese 人【ひと】.

*(FWIW, there's also [JLect.com](https://www.jlect.com/).  I've found their coverage to be a bit spottier for some things, and the site is not as user-friendly.  That said, they  do include resources for Okinawan, as well as other varieties of Ryūkyūan like Amami or Miyako, which can be super useful.)*

---

Please comment if the above does not fully address your question.

Comment: Sadly, the Shuri-Naha Dialect Dictionary was pulled offline by the university in early September.  Despite their notice that 「新システムは10月中旬公開予定しております」, it is now mid-January and we still don't have anything in place.  If anyone knows of a good online Okinawan dictionary, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

I conjecture it is from ぬ <- の. Why?

Okinawan actually has a regular sound change ぬ -> ん. For example, 犬{いぬ} -> いん. So I presume that somehow the regular sound changes got applied twice, and you get ん <- ぬ <- の.

Comment: You should think it terms of *sound correspondence* rather than *sound change* since we know Okinawan is not an offshoot of modern standard Japanese. They are sister languages rather than Okinawan being a daughter language of Japanese. Likely they have both changed from a distant common ancestor and we know from Old/Middle Japanese that modern standard Japanese has changed quite a lot.

Comment: Of course I meant sound change from some common ancestor. This common ancestor is much closer to the Japanese branch, and thus is usually approximated as Old/Middle Japanese. Really, Middle Japanese is okay, since we see no remnant of 上代特殊仮名遣い and all sound correspondences from Early Middle Japanese are perfectly regular. So ぬ does come from an ancestral の-like sound.

(Case in point: Japanese retains the big picture of the proto-Japonic verb system. Okinawan does something weird with forming everything as a compound with をる)

Comment: @ithisa, Eastern OJP had //nu// where Western (what became "standard") had //no//, such as 野 read as //nu// in Man'yōshū poems.  See also [the KDJ entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%87%8E-593886#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8).  So it's possible that the ancient common ancestor was actually _not_ necessarily closer to the Japanese branch.  Also, re: "weird" Okinawan verb conjugations with をる, consider that Japanese completion auxiliary ぬ likely derives from 往【い】ぬ "to go; to pass; to be done".  Weirdness is relative. 